# calculate JSON.stringify(obj) to sum value of string?

Tags: javascript

In my local storage I have some score value stored in array

```
var obj = localStorage.getItem("scoreList")
```

output

```
[0,10,10,0,10]
```

I want sum of this value like and return to data value

```
sum = 30
```

I have tried to convert into string value

```
var string = JSON.stringify(obj);
output "[0,10,10,0,10]"
```

How can I execute  this sum value ?

Comment: Yes it did answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
localStorage.getItem("scoreList").replace(/(\[|\])/g, '').split(",").map(x => parseFloat(x)).reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0)
```

a simple way:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("scoreList")).reduce((x, y) => x + y)
```

Comment: const ttlsum=  localStorage.getItem("scoreList").split(",").map(s => parseFloat(s)).reduce((x,y) => x+y)

console.log(ttlsum);  showed NaN value

Comment: @TanvirHasanEmon I updated it, hope to work

Comment: I did worked , thanks

Comment: Hey need more help , in initial when string doesn't store any value then it's show Cannot read properties of null (reading 'replace') . after store value its worked fine

Comment: did found answer. Have to use optional chaining (?.) to overcome this error

Comment: @TanvirHasanEmon I saw your comments now and I'm glad to see you found your answer

Answer (score 4):

`[0,10,10,0,10].reduce((sum, a) => sum + a, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

If you set the scoreList value as an array, that is:

```
localStorage.setItem('scoreList', [0,10,10,0,10])
```

When you get it back it will still be a string, so there's no need for any other kind of validation or data type transformation as you did with `JSON.stringfy`. The following shoud be enough:

```
const obj = localStorage.getItem("scoreList")
const total = obj.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item, 0);
//total = 30
```

Comment: it's show obj.reduce is not a function in my nuxt js appplication